# SpringBoot - Order of Bean creation and PostConstruct initialization

Tags: maven, spring-boot, initialization, javabeans, spring-annotations

I have a maven multimodule SpringBoot web application. I have a submodule, called *config-module* which has a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class PropertiesConfig {

    @Bean
    public YamlPropertiesFactoryBean errorPropertiesFromYamlFile() {
        final YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource("errorMessages.yml"));
        return yaml;
    }

}
```

I have a *web-app-module* maven module, which has the previous *config-module* as a dependency, and as an imported spring application.

In this main module, I also have a configuration class which loads new properties:

```
@Configuration
public class WebPropertiesConfig {

    @Bean
    public YamlPropertiesFactoryBean webPropertiesFromYamlFile() {
        final YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource("webProperties.yml"));
        return yaml;
    }

}
```

And in this module I also have a class like this:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "webpart")
public class ConfigPropertiesMapper {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //do something here
    }

}
```

And I don't know where it comes from, but the actual order of initialization is this (I checked it within debug mode):

1. `PropertiesConfig.errorPropertiesFromYamlFile()` bean creation from
   config-module
2. `ConfigPropertiesMapper.init()` PostConstruct initialization from
   web-app-module
3. `WebPropertiesConfig.webPropertiesFromYamlFile()` bean creation from
   web-app-module

Why is that? And how could I set the order to this?:

1. `PropertiesConfig.errorPropertiesFromYamlFile()`
2. `WebPropertiesConfig.webPropertiesFromYamlFile()`
3. `ConfigPropertiesMapper.init()`

I tried with the `@Order`, `@Qualifier`, `@Primary` annotations, but I could not solve this.

I know one more annotation: `@DependsOn`. But honestly, I don't want to use it, because then I need to add this annotation to every methods which has `@PostConstruct` on it.

Comment: Playing with the order of the beans instantiation is rarely a good idea. It is error prone and defeats the low-coupling of DI container. Please explain what you want to do and why `init()` should be invoked at the end.

Comment: I want this order because the config java files loads different properties, and I want to use those properties in the other java files, so therefore first I need to load the files.

Comment: Why don't you inject the Properties as a dependency in the bean class that needs it ?

Comment: I have a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer and I wanted to add more properties from the main maven module

Answer (score 2):

From the [API documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html)

"While such order values may influence priorities at injection points, please be aware that they do not influence singleton startup order which is an orthogonal concern determined by dependency relationships and @DependsOn declarations (influencing a runtime-determined dependency graph)."

You need to either a [@DependsOn](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html) annotation to control creation order.

Or else call all the init methods in one bean so you can control the order. If you inject the other beans you will be sure they have finished creation.

Something like:

```
@Component
public class InitBean {

   @Autowired
   privaPropertiesConfig propertiesConfig;

   @Autowired
   private WebPropertiesConfig webPropertiesConfig;

   @Autowired
   private ConfigPropertiesMapper configPropertiesMapper;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
       propertiesConfig.errorPropertiesFromYamlFile()
       webPropertiesConfig.webPropertiesFromYamlFile()
       configPropertiesMapper.init()    
    }
}
```

However you should probably add all your properties into one class, spring will find what it can, ignore what it can't and any values duplicate values in errroMessages will be overriden by webProperties.

```
@Component
@PropertySource(value={ "classpath:errorMessages.yml", "classpath:webProperties.yml"}, ignoreResourceNotFound="true))
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "webpart")
public class ConfigPropertiesMapper {
   ...    
}
```

Comment: But if I just call the methods, it won't be a bean creation, no?

Comment: why is the order important? Are you trying t override the same property for web, that you have in config-module?

Comment: I have a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer and I wanted to add more properties from the main maven module

Answer (score 1):

There are different mechanisms of bean *initialization* (not bean *creation*) in Spring/Boot. They can be used regardless of bean dependencies, if desired.

The order (mid. 2020 with Spring Boot 2.3.2) is:

1. direct bean initialization with `@PostConstruct` or `InitializingBean`
2. `SmartInitializingSingleton`s
3. `SmartLifecycle` beans
4. `ApplicationStartedEvent` is triggered
5. `ApplicationReadyEvent` is triggered

(there are other events too, of course)